# Hiding the get variables

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url that is constructed using get variables like

```
location.href = this.href +'?type='+ escape($('#type_of_station').html()) + '&count='+ escape($('.number_changer').attr("id").slice(-1));
```

which gives me a url like the following

```
http://posnation.com/pre_config/pre_config_step_2.php?type=Grocery&count=2
```

on the following page I grab the variables via PHP

```
<p id="type_of_station" class="text left"><?php $_GET['type'] != "" ? print str_replace("_", " ", $_GET['type']) : print "Food Pos System" ?></p>
```

This works great but the url is kind of ugly. Is there a way to maybe hide this and still have the get variables available to me on the next page

Comment: @Col to transport variables from page to page, identified by a random key? Why not?

Comment: @Pekka won't that make bookmarking URLs impossible?

Comment: @Pekka well if URL were chosen wrong as a transport already - may be. But in general to use session to hide anything from the url is BAD idea.

Comment: @aularon: This appears to be step 2 in a configuration process given the script name `pre_config_step_2.php`. I would think preventing bookmarking would actually be desirable here. But I am just pontificating.

Comment: @aularon sure, but the same is the case with POST

Comment: You should avoid `escape()`, which results in a mix of percent-encoded ISO-8859-1 and Unicode escape sequences with `%` instead of `\ `. Use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Functions:encodeURIComponent) instead, it gives clean percent-encoded UTF-8 which is easy to decode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make url look nice is one thing.
To hide url data is another. Never hide anything. Or you will make your site unusable.

Comment: This depends on the context, but is often true.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in the example provided I don't see how using POST instead of GET makes the site unusable. It does prevent bookmarking of the URLs, but these URLs seem to be steps in a configuration process. Major sites like Dell use POST for configuration of their systems. And if bookmarking is desired, a better approach with complex data would be a "Bookmark This"/permalink solution.

Answer (score 2):

You want to POST your variables to the server rather than sending them as GET requests.

In PHP you can access the variables POST-ed with the $_POST variable.

Simple form:

form.php

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
   username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br/>
</form>
```

The 'username' POST-ed could then be accessed in the process.php file by

process.php

```
echo $_POST['username'];
```

Unlike GET requests, values sent to the server are not shown in the URL.

Comment: NEVER use POST where GET should be, son. These methods are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: How do you know GET should be used here?

Comment: No one said they were interchangeable.  But it is one way to approach the problem presented.

Comment: If you use post you can't access pages directly using the URL.

Comment: @Stian: true, but not everything is about accessing the URL or SEO.  Some things don't need to be accessed again or permalinked.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`, or save them in a session and go to the next page.

EDIT:
That is if you **really** want to completely hide the variables. As the others are suggesting: it's better to use mod_rewrite to make it look nicer, without hiding the data.

Answer (score 0):

I fell on your post on searching solutions just for this problem.. - and even it is a late answer, maybe it will help someone:

For my use, I got a simple solution:

Just add into your index.php file after starting the php session the following line:

```
if(isset($_GET))
{
header("Location:index.php");
$_SESSION['relink'] = $_GET;
}
```

You will have any GET value in the SESSION['relink'] variable. And then you redirect to the index.php file. There will be any visible traces in your browser address. After it is on you to check any value of the array before using it. But at least your browser address is CLEAN!